# devise with filterrific gem error

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

i get the following error

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `filterrific' for #<Class:0x00000004fa5880> (NoMethodError)
from /home/sam/Desktop/academicv2/app/models/user.rb:175:in `<class:User>'
from /home/sam/Desktop/academicv2/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

its because i have used a gem called filterrific. its working ok for all of my models except user model which is managed by devise.

i did this in user.rb

```
 filterrific(
  #:default_settings => { :sorted_by => 'created_at_desc' },
  :filter_names => [
    :with_username,
    :with_ratings        
  ]        
)
```

i followed the following the following documentation http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm getting the same error